# SAS SQL: search for duplicates among potentially non-unqiue fileds

Tags: sql, sas

I need to clean up the database that has various types of duplicate records made by human error. An example is below:

```
+-----+------------+-----+-----+
| ID     |  Name          | 
+========+=========+=====+=====+
|  1001  |  John Smith    |  
|  1002  |  John Smith    |  
|  3300  |  Amy J. Lin    |  
|  3300  |  Amy Jing Lin  |  
|  3300  |  Amy Ling      |  
|  6887  |  Paul Wayne    |
|  7890  |  Paul K. Wayne |  
|  8432  |  Paul K. Wane  |
```

Due to errors made, I could be seeing

1. the same name with different ID (1001 and 1002),
2. the same ID (3300) with slightly different names due to typo, and
3. different ID with slight different names.

I tried to use "group by" and "Having (records > 1)" but this only gets me results for #2, not the whole picture.

Would anyone have any suggestions? Due to typo in the data, I also need a function to search for similar words in the name field.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isnt an easy way to do this. You probably need some human intervention.

For case #1 You can have two different person name `Jhon Smith` so a real person need to decide if that is an error. You can also use a `GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` But just to raise a warning flag

#2 can be done with the `GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

#3 you can get some matching using `text search` functions

Comment: Thanks, Juan. How would a "text search" function look like in this case?

Comment: something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568.aspx